# Password length error wont show up

Tags: php, registration

I have an error ("Password length must be between 6 and 32 characters long") set up so when users try to register with a password less than 6 characters, they get that error and are unable to sign up, but no matter how short the password, the error doesn't come up, it just continues with registration. Please help, thanks!
Here is the code:

```
<?php

$submit = $_POST['submit'];

$name = strip_tags($_POST['fullnamefield']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['regemailfield']);

$password = strip_tags($_POST['regpasswordfield']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['regpasswordconfirmfield']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if ($submit)
{
  if ($name&&$email&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
  {
    $password = md5($password);
    $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);

    if ($password==$repeatpassword)
    {
      if (strlen($name)>32||strlen($email)>1024)
      {
        echo "Length of name or email is too long. Please try again";
      }
      else
      {
        if (strlen($password)>32||strlen($password)<6)
        {
          echo "password must be between 6 and 25 character!";
        }
      }
    }
    else
      echo "Your passwords do not match!";
  }
  else
    echo "Please fill in all fields!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to limit the length of the password to 32 characters? That's like purposely limiting your security.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the length BEFORE you use md5()

Comment: @checkit923 simply limit your password field max length 32 in html

Comment: @AbdullahAdam, that is a very bad idea if you're relying on it for security. ALL user data should be checked/sanitized server side.

Comment: @mike actually i think the users want to limit password length max 32 
than when he gets the data in PHP the password is already comes with max 32 so that he can directly do other things 
maybe i am wrong what do you say is it right to do

Comment: @AbdullahAdam, no HTML or JavaScript will ever be able to prevent users from submitting whatever they want to your script.

Comment: Hey guys, im following a tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1zaEiZawsI&feature=fvwrel
& they tell me to do that, and it works there, just not for me.

Comment: Check for minimum password length, not for maximum length ... once you have applied the hash it won't matter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you Hash the Password in MD5 and that changes the $password variable to a 32 Characters String

Answer (score 0):

When you send the password in the md5 function, that function actually creates a 32 character hexadecimal number (hash) and so your checking is useless.